# jQuery isotope - Page jumps to top when clicking on embedded youtube video in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, jquery-isotope

I have a page using jQuery isotope with a masonry layout. There are a number of divs, one is a youtube video embedded as html5.

For some reason, the page jumps back to the top of the page when clicking on the youtube video in firefox. It works perfectly in Safari/Chrome.

If anyone has any ideas what may be causing this, it would be greatly appreciated!

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/iwehev/2

Answer (score 2):

You're example didn't do what you're describing for me. It sounds like you're looking for `preventDefault();` though. Use it within a click function of what ever element is giving you issues on click.

```
$('a').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#wall').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    animationEngine: 'css,
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    transformsEnabled: false //Disable transformations
});
```

Add the transformsEnabled: false to the isotope function.